# me/calender/calenderview return 404

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

For one user, in one tenant, `me/calender/calenderview?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}` is returning `404`:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "55f9559d-80af-458a-9276-278acf2c0286",
            "date": "2020-01-20T13:08:18"
        }
    }
}
```

client-request-id is `61894e75-d190-4338-a0a4-e9f81ee3af4e`
request-id is `55f9559d-80af-458a-9276-278acf2c0286`

Comment: Does GET /me/calendar work?

Comment: Are you sure this user has an Exchange Online mailbox provisioned?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur do not know yet waiting for response from customer

Answer (score 0):

A startDateTime and endDateTime parameter are required.

Like:

```
/me/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: sorry i forgot add those parameters in question, we are passing those parameters

Comment: Okay, how do you obtain your token? The "me" url only works for user obtained tokens. You also need the delegated API permissions for the calendar.

Comment: Issue is it works for other users in same tenant except one user,
And our application has tenant wide consent for permissions

Comment: @Gautam I havent heard back from our customer engagement team, so I'm not sure

Comment: Any update on this? Facing the same issue